# Does "hereby" sound too serious at the end of a letter to the visa office?

Tags: word-in-context

Well, I had to write a letter to the visa office explaining the reasons why I apply for the visa and what my background is in a brief fashion. And at the end of the letter, I used this sentence:

> I hereby apply for the study permit so as to leave me enough time to
>   plan my...

Does that sound okay to the native ears? I fear it almost sounds like I am about to claim a right in a law-related context or to declare something to the public.

Comment: It does sound a little like a legal proclamation and I personally wouldn't use it ... but the visa office probably sees a lot of oddly phrased letters from foreign students, so I doubt they'll care one way or the other.

Comment: Tip: Try _"I am now applying..."_ rather than _"I hereby apply..."_

Comment: Oh I just took it out and said, "for the reason mentioned above, I apply for..." I hope that sounds good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hereby" is a bit too formal and archaic for most contexts including this one. It is generally [falling out of common use](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hereby&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chereby%3B%2Cc0). There are several good suggested alternatives in the comments. For example,

> I am now applying...

or

> For the reasons above, I am applying for...

depending on the rest of the letter.